# Microsoft Office: Your account has multiple licenses

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-office, license

So I have an older laptop which came with Office Home & Student 2016 for PC. I now got a new laptop with Office Home & Student 2021.

Both laptops use the same live.com account for the licenses. On the new laptop, I clicked on the Excel Activate Button & I get the following message

[image]

When I go to my Services & Subscription Page on account.microsoft.com, I can copy the 2016 key & but though I see my 2021 license, it doesn't show/allow me to copy the key so I can activate my Office using the key.

So what do I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to go the services & subscription page on the Microsoft site & on the 2021 license which was shown there without the key, there was an install option. On clicking it, it redownloaded the product & installed it. After installing, when I clicked on the activate, I still got the same message about multiple licenses, but there was an update license option which when I clicked activated the product. I don't remember if the Update License option was shown earlier or not. I also don't remember what was the original version which the laptop came with (I assume it was the same one which was downloaded because they won't sell the laptop preinstalled with a license & product of diff versions)

Either way, the original message was highly user-unfriendly, scary & didn't make sense. They could as well have chosen the right license & updated it themselves if I already had the right license stored in my account.

Comment: @DrMoishePippik -absolutely not

Comment: It seems that the key is no longer displayed starting from Office 2019 on Services & Subscription Page